blosc vs blosc2: parallel compression
Could you, please, help me to understand if the blosc library supports parallel compression?
My understand is that parallel compression is supported by blosc2, but I am having difficulty finding a definitive answer on whether it is supported by the first version of blosc.
Setting BLOSC_NTHREADS environment variable to 10 does not seem to have any effect on the CPU usage during blosc data compression in pandas when data is written to an HDF5 file.
